# Protocol Enumerable not implemented for struct. How to convert the struct into an enumerable?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using structs to create custom models in a Phoenix / Elixir app. Like so:

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  defstruct username: nil, email: nil, password: nil, hashed_password: nil
end

new_user = %MyApp.User{email: "email@example.com", hashed_password: nil, password: "secret", username: "ole"}
```

In order to use it with my database adapter, I need the data to be enumerable. Which a struct apparently isn't. At least I receive this error:

```
(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for %MyApp.User{ ...
```

So I tried my luck using a comprehension. Which of course also doesn't work, because the struct isn't enumerable (stupid me)

```
enumberable_user = for {key, val} <- new_user, into: %{}, do: {key, val}
```

How can I convert the data to an enumerable map?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Map.from_struct/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Map.html#from_struct/1) to do the conversion to a map at the point of insertion to the database. This will remove the `__struct__` key.

You used to be able to derive the Enumerable protocol, but it seems that it was accidental. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3821

> Ouch, it was an accident that deriving worked before, I don't think we should fix it. Maybe we could update the v1.1 changelog to make it clear but I wouldn't do a code change.

```
defmodule User do
  @derive [Enumerable]
  defstruct name: "", age: 0
end

Enum.each %User{name: "jose"}, fn {k, v} ->
  IO.puts "Got #{k}: #{v}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I created module [make_enumerable](https://github.com/basiliscos/ex-make_enumerable) to address that issue:

```
defmodule Bar do
  use MakeEnumerable
  defstruct foo: "a", baz: 10
end

iex> import Bar
iex> Enum.map(%Bar{}, fn({k, v}) -> {k, v} end)
[baz: 10, foo: "a"]
```